# adding unique identifiers on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data sheet of 900+ entries that I have numbered with the first row starting at 100 using `=ROW(A100)`

That just increases with each row.

Would I be able to add a word in front of that number? It would be the same word for each entry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use:

```
=ROW(A100)&" WORD HERE"
```

Or

```
="WORD HERE "&ROW(A100)&" ANOTHER WORD HERE"
```

Where the `&` will work to join the parts as a string.